# How to use WHILE inside WHEN MATCHED THEN in MsSQL?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

What I am trying to do is pass a make the MERGE statement dynamic using a stored procedure. I had an EXECUTE() statement in there to make it dynamic but I have removed that part to make it a little simpler for now.

I am passing two tables, their matching column and the rest of the column mappings to the SP. But I cannot get a WHILE loop to work inside the WHEN MATCHED THEN part. Is there a way?

```
CREATE TYPE MergeColumns AS TABLE 
( Id INT,
  SourceColumn NVARCHAR(10)
, DestinationColumn NVARCHAR(10) );
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE MergeWithParameters
    @Table1 VARCHAR(10), 
    @Table2 VARCHAR(10),
    @MatchingColumn VARCHAR(10),
    @MatchingColumns MergeColumns READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @RowCount INT
    SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM @MatchingColumns) 


    -- Declare an iterator
    DECLARE @I INT
    -- Initialize the iterator
    SET @I = 1


    MERGE INTO TableB AS b
    USING TableA AS a
        ON a.Id = b.Id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
    WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
    BEGIN
        b.DestinationColumn = a.SourceColumn;
    FROM @MatchingColumns WHERE Id = @I;
    END
END
GO
```

Here is the call to the SP.

```
DECLARE @TableOne AS MergeColumns
INSERT INTO @TableOne VALUES(1, 'Name', 'Name')
EXEC MergeWithParameters 'TableA', 'TableB', 'Id', @TableOne
```

The error I am getting right now is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MergeWithParameters, Line 25
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHILE'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1,
>   Procedure MergeWithParameters, Line 27 Incorrect syntax near 'b'.

Comment: You haven't specified END for While's BEGIN.

Comment: You cannot use WHILE inside MERGE, can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @DH__ Oh thanks.. added that. But the problem still persists.

Comment: See schema and example on this site and correct your code.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx.   If you find any issue in that, contact me.

Comment: try this:
`MERGE INTO TableB AS b
USING (SELECT T1.Id, T2.SourceColumn FROM TableA T1 INNER JOIN @MatchingColumns T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id) AS a
 ON a.Id = b.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
 b.DestinationColumn = a.SourceColumn;`

Comment: You can't parameterize the columns to update in a merge statement, if that's what you're trying to do.